# Area of the union of two disks with centers one unit apart and radii of 1

Tags: geometry

I am trying to do Problems Plus 4 in Chapter 7 of Stewart's calculus textbook, and I just want to make sure my work is correct:
"The centers of two disks with radius 1 are one unit apart. Find the area of the union of the two disks."

I started by trying to find the area of their intersection since the area of their union should be (pi)+(pi-(area of the intersection)).

The two circles should form an equilateral triangle (by Proposition 1, Book 1 of Euclid's Elements), so there are two central angles of 120 degrees (when you consider both of the triangles formed; below is a figure showing Prop. 1 to make it clearer). [image: Proposition 1 in Euclid's Elements] The area of the intersection should be 2pi/3 - (the intersection of the two sectors). The area of the intersection of the two sectors (and here's the part I'm not sure about) should be the area of the two equilateral triangles, which is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Is this correct?

If it is, the final answer should be

$$\pi+(\pi-(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}))$$

Thanks!

Comment: Your final answer is correct, but I don't understand your reasoning. The area of the intersection is not the two equilateral triangles, otherwise your final answer would be $2\pi - (2)(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$. You would not account for the four segments between the chords and circumference of the circle.

Comment: I was saying I thought the two equilateral triangles were the overlap of the two sectors, not the intersection itself. Each of the sectors had an area of pi/3, so the answer I got for the intersection itself was 2*(pi/3)-(the overlap of the sectors), or 2pi/3-sqrt(3)/2

Comment: Ah OK I see what you are saying - yes your logic makes sense.